# Setup to View Dev Site Via localhost

Tags: apache2, localhost

I'm using `Ubuntu 22.04` and `PHP 8.1.2` (just noting the php in case it matters)

I have a few Live working websites I manage. I would like to set up my local machine to be able to view changes in a browser as I make them, before pushing them live. I.e: `localhost/LivingMuayThai/index.html`

I also have other sites I work on. The sites I manage are all in a directory off of my home diretory: `Websites/`  I.e: `Websites/LivingMuayThai/` or `Websites/SacNomads/`, etc...

I have `apache2` installed and working, and I can see the default apache2-web-page when I go to `localhost` now. I know it is in `/var/www/html/index.html`. As noted, my sites are not in that directory.

What do I need to do to see the sites I have in my `Websites/` directory via `localhost/...`?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60678203/10477326